# GSM modem returning what I send via USART terminal

Tags: at-command

I am using at command to control a USB modem. When I send a command to this modem I receive some data including the command I send. Example:

> AT
>
> OK
>
> AT+CUSD=1,"*778#",15
>
> OK
>
> +CUSD: 0,"Balance: 7.50 TK. Validity: 02-Sep-13. Bonus: 0.00TK. Free Min: 0.",64

But what I want is like this:

> OK
>
> OK
>
> +CUSD: 0,"Balance: 7.50 TK. Validity: 02-Sep-13. Bonus: 0.00TK. Free Min: 0.",64

Is there any at command available that can prevent this modem to show sending command again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set) on the Hayes command set used by modems, there are two commands that control the echoing behavior of the modems:

- `E0` turns the echoing off, so the modem will not repeat the command that was sent to it
- `E1` turns echoing back on

What you are looking for is the `E0` or the `E` command, where the latter is only a shorthand for the first one.